# React TypeScript return type component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my code:

```
 const options = {
    dataFormat: (rowId: number) => <TableActions rowId={id} options={tableActionsOptions} />,
 };
```

I want to return `<TableActions />` in dataFormat. However, I am getting the following error:

```
JSX element type 'false | Element' is not a constructor function for JSX elements
```

Comment: Please try this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356

Comment: How is TableActions defined? I think the error message means that Typescript thinks it may be false.